# JIRA - upload a file to server from add-on admin page

Tags: java, jira, jira-plugin

I'm developing an add-on for JIRA that needs a file to be uploaded. The file contains rules in JSON format that defines the behaviour of the add-on. 
I've defined a multipart-config servlet and a multipart/form-data form in admin page. But I can't retrieve any part with getPart method at servlet side, it seems to arrive "empty", like no form was defined.

These are some pieces of my code:

**upload rules template (vm):**

```
...
<form id="upload-rules" class="aui" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" id="uploading" name="uploading" value="y">
    <input type="hidden" id="test" name="test" value="y">

    <div class="field-group">
        <label for="file">Rules config file<span class="aui-icon icon-required">(required)</span></label>
        <input type="file" id="file" name="file" class="file">
    </div>

    <div class="field-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="button" name="upload" id="upload">
        <a href="$baseURL/plugins/servlet/upm">Cancel</a>            
    </div>

</form>
...
```

**RulesServlet.java**

```
...
@Named("RulesServlet")
@MultipartConfig
public class RulesServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    ...

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        LOG.debug("doGet method called.");

        //Only admin users are admitted
        if (!isAdminUser(request)) {
            redirectToLogin(request, response);
            return;
        }
        AutoEscalateConfig autoEscalateConfig = null;       

        ...stuff for getting configs...

        if ("preupload".equals(request.getParameter("op"))) {

            Map<String, Object> context = getContextWithCommonParams(autoEscalateConfig);

            // Render the template with the issue inside the context
            response.setContentType(CONTENT_TYPE);
            renderer.render(UPLOAD_TEMPLATE, context, response.getWriter());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        LOG.debug("doPost method called.");

        //Only admin users are admitted
        if (!isAdminUser(request)) {
            redirectToLogin(request, response);
            return;
        }

        try {
            LOG.debug("Updating rules...");

            LOG.debug("Request content type: " + request.getContentType());
            LOG.debug("Request parameterMap size: " + request.getParameterMap().size());
            LOG.debug("Request parts size: " + request.getParts().size());

            Part filePart = request.getPart("file"); // Retrieves <input type="file" name="file">
            String fileName = Paths.get(getSubmittedFileName(filePart)).getFileName().toString(); // MSIE fix.
            InputStream fileContent = filePart.getInputStream();                

            ...stuff to get rules from file...

            response.setContentType(CONTENT_TYPE);
            renderer.render(UPLOAD_TEMPLATE, context, response.getWriter());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Error creating escalate rules.", e);
            throw new ServletException(e);
        }

    }   

    private static String getSubmittedFileName(Part part) {
        for (String cd : part.getHeader("content-disposition").split(";")) {
            if (cd.trim().startsWith("filename")) {
                String fileName = cd.substring(cd.indexOf('=') + 1).trim().replace("\"", "");
                return fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('/') + 1).substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('\\') + 1); // MSIE fix.
            }
        }
        return null;
    }   

}
...
```

**atlassian-plugin.xml**

```
...
<servlet key="mim-autoescalate-upload-rules-servlet" i18n-name-key="mim-autoescalate-rules-upload-servlet.name" 
        class="cat.palma.jira.escalate.ui.RulesServlet" name="MIM Autoescalate Plugin Upload Rules Servlet">
    <description key="mim-autoescalate-rules-upload-servlet.description">The rules upload servlet to populate the MIM Autoescalate Plugin rule table</description>
    <url-pattern>/mimautoescalateplugin/rules</url-pattern>
</servlet>
...
<web-item key="mim-autoescalate-link-upload-rules" i18n-name-key="mim-autoescalate-link-upload-rules.name"
        name="MIM Autoescalate Plugin Setup Rules Link" section="admin_plugins_menu/mim-autoescalate-section" weight="1010">
    <description key="mim-autoescalate-link-upload-rules.description">The Setup Page Link for escalate rules of MIM Autoescalate Plugin</description>
    <label key="mim-autoescalate-link-upload-rules.label"></label>
    <link linkId="mim-autoescalate-link-upload-rules-link">/plugins/servlet/mimautoescalateplugin/rules?op=preupload</link>
</web-item>
...
```

**pom.xml**

```
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
...
<properties>
    <jira.version>7.7.1</jira.version>
    <amps.version>6.3.15</amps.version>
    <plugin.testrunner.version>1.2.3</plugin.testrunner.version>
    <atlassian.spring.scanner.version>1.2.13</atlassian.spring.scanner.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <atlassian.template.renderer.version>2.0.0</atlassian.template.renderer.version>
    <activeobjects.version>1.5.0</activeobjects.version>
    <spring.version>4.2.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <gson.version>2.3.1</gson.version>
...
</properties>
...
```

After picking up a file and press upload button, following messages from servlet debug appear in log:

```
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2018-05-17 09:00:55,820 DEBUG admin [c.p.j.escalate.ui.RulesServlet] doPost method called.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2018-05-17 09:00:55,821 DEBUG admin [c.p.j.escalate.ui.RulesServlet] User performing action admin.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2018-05-17 09:00:55,822 DEBUG admin [c.p.j.escalate.ui.RulesServlet] Updating rules...
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2018-05-17 09:00:55,822 DEBUG admin [c.p.j.escalate.ui.RulesServlet] Request content type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryxRnbEsLcgjpzyKWn
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2018-05-17 09:00:55,822 DEBUG admin [c.p.j.escalate.ui.RulesServlet] Request parameterMap size: 1
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2018-05-17 09:00:55,823 DEBUG admin [c.p.j.escalate.ui.RulesServlet] Request parts size: 0
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2018-05-17 09:00:55,823 ERROR admin [c.p.j.escalate.ui.RulesServlet] Error creating escalate rules.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] java.lang.NullPointerException
```

ParameterMap contains only "op" parameter from link (".../plugins/servlet/mimautoescalateplugin/rules?op=preupload"). 
*request.getParts().size()* is 0, so *request.getPart("file")* returns *null*, no file is uploaded. Seems like no form was defined.

Does anyone has any idea about what's going on or where error is?

Thanks in advance!!